# Can one affect the appearance of components of a control?

Tags: mac-os-x, interface, gui-construction

I'd like to control the appearance of the components of a `TabView[]` control.
Such a control appears constructed of `Button`s, `ButtonBar`, and `Panel`.

Some examples follow to illustrate my problem.

```
appearances = {"DialogBox", "Palette", "FramedPalette", "Frameless"};
Button[1, Print[1], Appearance -> #] & /@ appearances
ButtonBar[{1 :> Print[1], 2 :> Print[2]}, Appearance -> #] & /@ appearances
TabView[{a, b}, Appearance -> #] & /@ appearances
```

[image]

In the above code I can change the appearances of an individual `Button[]` but not buttons in a `ButtonBar[]` or a `TabView[]`.

```
Button[1, Print[1], Background -> Yellow] 
ButtonBar[{1 :> Print[1], 2 :> Print[2]}, Background -> Yellow] 
TabView[{a, b}, Background -> Yellow]
```

[image]

The above presents a similar problem.  Note that in the `ButtonBar[]` you can see a yellow halo around the entire control.

Finally:

```
Panel[a, ImageSize -> 100, Background -> Yellow]
TabView[{a, b}, ImageSize -> 100, Background -> Yellow]
```

[image]

A similar problem, I can affect `Panel[]` but not the panel component of a `TabView[]`.

So, does anyway exist to reach settings that affect the component levels of a complex control?

Any workarounds appreciated.

...

As this seems relevant, I run version 9 on OS X.

Comment: Mm8 8.0 on WinXP: `TabView[{a, b}, Background -> Yellow]` http://i.stack.imgur.com/zwTYn.png

Comment: I doubt if this is possible, especially on Mac OS where customizing the UI widgets is not exactly condoned by Apple. Aside from that, the range of possible customizations is probably too platform-specific as the widgets seem to be the standard ones provided by the underlying OS. You might have better luck building an interface in Java.

Comment: @belisarius -- Very curious that it has changed in v9.  Any speculation as to why?  I ask, because it might help me/us better understand the direction of development.

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- While I recognize that this doesn't appear possible, why Wolfram wouldn't have made it possible?  At some level they build up these controls from components.  What prevents developers from exposing the methods/attributes of the components?  For that matter, why wouldn't they?  Maybe I've missed something, but it seems like a trivial thing to do.  Don't TabView controls already provide one the ability to change things at the same level of exposure e.g., one can change the text in a tab or the content of a panel, so why not the specific appearance? Just wondering.

Comment: @Jagra No, really not. Sorry.

Comment: @Jagra OS implementors (specifically UI designers) don't necessarily consider it useful or desirable to offer unlimited customization of the widgets, especially if they aim to present a consistent appearance for the OS and its applications. Changing the text of a tab or the content of a panel is an essential aspect of its functionality, while things like scrolling diagonal text or a flashing background might be seen as detrimental to its purpose. As a result one can easily imagine that these aspects might be hard-coded in the UI library. There is also a non-zero testing cost for such features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always create your own custom controls.  This is a *lot* of work, but it also gives you unlimited flexibility.  You can even create completely new kinds of control.

Scroll down to the last section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) to see an example.

If you're aiming for a custom `TabView`-like control, I'd start with `PaneSelector`.

Here's a primitive example (just a start, not meant for final use):

```
value = "one"

tab[text_] := 
 Style[Button[text, value = text, Appearance -> None, 
   ImageMargins -> 10], Background -> Hue[RandomReal[], 1, 1]]

Column[{
  Row[tab /@ {"one", "two", "three"}],
  PaneSelector[{"one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3}, 
   Dynamic[value]]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Seems like the way to go, +1.  I had hoped for a simpler life.

Comment: @Jagra There may be simpler ways, I'd wait for more answers.  I'd only do this as a last resort.  It's clear *how* to do it, but it's not pleasant.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is that yes, you can affect the appearance of components of a control but the problem in this case is that your list of appearances

```
appearances = {"DialogBox", "Palette", "FramedPalette", "Frameless"};
```

are only valid `Button` appearances and that is why they have no effect of `ButtonBar` or `TabView`. When you use valid appearances it works fine:

```
Button[1, Print[1], Appearance -> #] & /@ {"DialogBox", "Palette", 
  "FramedPalette", "Frameless"}
ButtonBar[{1 :> Print[1], 2 :> Print[2]}, 
   Appearance -> #] & /@ {"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Row"}
TabView[{a, b}, Appearance -> #] & /@ {"Limited"}
```

(although the example is a bit limited to fully display some of the appearances)

[image]

`ButtonBar` is just a construction in which buttons are placed in a grid. If you have a look at the underlying expression you will get a feel for how you can make your own customized `ButtonBar`:

```
Grid[{{Button[1, Null, Appearance -> {"AbuttingRight"}], 
   Button[2, Null, Appearance -> {"AbuttingLeft"}]}},
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Regarding `Panel` and `TabView`, you are right and this always feels like a limitation when using `TabView` (on Macs anyway). And on Macs nested `TabView` looks pretty horrible because of the "locked in" panelling. As a type of work around, not perfect by any means, I wrap my `TabView` elements in `Panel`:

```
TabView[{Panel[a, Background -> Yellow, ImageSize -> {578, 349}]}, 
 ImageSize -> {600, 400}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround wrapping the TabView elements in Panel and congratulations on reaching 10k.